# Font-size in CSS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to specify the size of the text of buttons located in the footer of a JQuery Mobile application page (chart1). The class is named 'footer-button' and is styled in the code below. It doesn't matter what kind of values I specify (px, em or pt), the text size doesn't seem to change. Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<style>

    .ui-page { background: #2f2d2d;}

    .footerBar{
        min-height: 80px;
    }

    .footer-button{
        min-height: 80px;
        font-size: 20;
        word-wrap: normal;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>
<!-- code for the main page -->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="main-page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
       <h1>Data Collector</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Collected Data Available:</li>
            <li><a href="#chart1" id="btn1" data-transition="slide">Car</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>&#169 KLH</h4>
    </div>
</div>



<!-- code for the chart 1 page -->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="chart1">
    <div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="true" class="headerBar">
       <a href="#main-page" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Car Crashes</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"  data-position="fixed">
        <div id="containerYear"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footerBar">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#chart1" data-role="tab" class="ui-btn-active footer-button">Last 12 Months</a></li>
                <li><a href="#chart2" data-role="tab" class="footer-button">Last 30 Days</a></li>
                <li><a href="#chart3" data-role="tab" class="footer-button">Last 7 Days</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to add a type of font size - `px`, `pt`, `em`, `%`

Comment: JQM is overriding your style. Remove jqm css include and see if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target this class .ui-btn-text

So...

```
.footer-button .ui-btn-text {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the source with Chrome, you will see that JQuery Mobile adds some intervening classes.

To make a long story short: this works

```
.footer-button .ui-btn-text {
    min-height: 80px;
    font-size: 50px;
    word-wrap: normal;
```

}

Comment: Repeated answer is repeated.

Comment: You're also applying `min-height` and `word-wrap` properties to `ui-btn-text` with this code. This will give a different output.

Answer (score -1):

Add unit suffix ("px") to the font-size like this:

```
.footer-button{
        min-height: 80px;
        font-size: 20px;
        word-wrap: normal;
    }
```

Comment: -1 Read the question `It doesn't matter what kind of values I specify (px, em or pt)`